# Testing that custom Spring Boot AutoConfiguration is valid

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I've decided to write quite a trivial test to check that my Spring Boot auto-configuration works - all the needed beans are created along with their dependencies.

AutoConfiguration is:

```
package org.project.module.autoconfigure;

import org.project.module.SomeFactory;
import org.project.module.SomeProducer;
import org.project.module.SomeServiceClient;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Spring Boot simple auto-configuration.
 *
 * @author istepanov
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.project.module.support")
public class SomeAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public SomeFactory someFactory() {
        return new SomeFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public SomeServiceClient someServiceClient() {
        return new SomeServiceClient();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public SomeProducer someProducer() {
        return new SomeProducer();
    }
}
```

And test is:

```
package org.project.module.autoconfigure;

import org.project.module.SomeFactory;
import org.project.module.SomeProducer;
import org.project.module.SomeServiceClient;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

/**
 * Tests for {@code SomeAutoConfiguration}.
 *
 * @author istepanov
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeAutoConfiguration.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class SomeAutoConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeFactory someFactory;
    @Autowired
    private SomeServiceClient someServiceClient;
    @Autowired
    private SomeProducer someProducer;

    @Test
    public void someFactory_isNotNull() {
        assertThat(someFactory).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void someServiceClient_isNotNull() {
        assertThat(someServiceClient).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void someProducer_isNotNull() {
        assertThat(someProducer).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

But actually test fails with exception - dependent beans, which are expected to be loaded with `@ComponentScan`, are actually missing:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.java:49)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'someFacade': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSomeMetrics' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'someMetrics': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setCounterService' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'someMetrics': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setCounterService' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'someMetrics': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setCounterService' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 54 more
```

Any ideas what have I missed?

P.S.: Also adding the missing SomeMetrics:

```
package org.project.module.support.metrics;

import org.project.module.support.SomeProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.GaugeService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

/**
 * Customization for Spring Actuator, defines application-specific counters and metrics.
 *
 * @author istepanov
 */
@Component
public class SomeMetrics {

    @Value("${const.metrics.some.connections.current:some.connections.created}")
    private String connectorsCurrent;
    @Value("${const.metrics.some.connections.idle:some.connections.idle}")
    private String connectorsIdle;
    @Value("${const.metrics.some.connections.max:some.connections.max}")
    private String connectorsMax;

    private CounterService counterService;
    private GaugeService gaugeService;
    private SomeProperties someProperties;

    @Autowired
    public void setSomeProperties(SomeProperties someProperties) {
        this.someProperties = someProperties;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCounterService(CounterService counterService) {
        this.counterService = counterService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setGaugeService(GaugeService gaugeService) {
        this.gaugeService = gaugeService;
    }

    /**
     * Use mocks for {@link CounterService} and {@link GaugeService} if CRMBO is not configured properly.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (someProperties.isMock()) {
            counterService = mock(CounterService.class);
            gaugeService = mock(GaugeService.class);
        }
    }

    public void decrementConnectorsCurrent() {
        this.counterService.decrement(connectorsCurrent);
    }

    public void incrementConnectorsCurrent() {
        this.counterService.increment(connectorsCurrent);
    }

    public void decrementConnectorsIdle() {
        this.counterService.decrement(connectorsIdle);
    }

    public void incrementConnectorsIdle() {
        this.counterService.increment(connectorsIdle);
    }

    public void decrementConnectorsMax() {
        this.counterService.decrement(connectorsMax);
    }

    public void incrementConnectorsMax() {
        this.counterService.increment(connectorsMax);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation on one of the beans?

Comment: No change - same exception.

Comment: As I understand, code `@ComponentScan("org.project.module.support")` is ignored, so low-level beans are not created.

Comment: Can we see your POM- or Gradle-files? The error message mentions things like `someMetrics` and `counterService`, none of which seem to have anything to do with your auto-configuration. Unless you changed the name in the example code, but not in the stacktrace?

Comment: It's custom auto-configuration. I develop a small library for corporate usage and decided to make it "auto-configurable". So now I'd like to cover this custom configuration with tests - just to ensure that all the required beans are created. And here comes the issue.

Comment: And yes, I change some custom names - both in code and stacktrace, just to be on the safe side :) I've also published sample code for `SomeMetrics` class - it's just a customisation for Spring Actuator.

Comment: Does your test run if you remove the `@ComponentScan` from `SomeAutoConfiguration`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like a regular Spring configuration issue to me, not necessarily a Spring Boot auto-configuration one.

In your test, you've only configured `SomeAutoConfiguration` to initialize your application context, and thanks to the `@ComponentScan` annotation, it'll discover other components to set up, like `SomeMetrics`. `SomeMetrics` relies on certain Spring Boot Actuator beans to exist, which they don't due to the narrow context configuration in your test.

You'll have to add more beans on the context if you want things to work, or add some conditions to your `SomeMetrics` component to prevent it from being created unless the necessary beans exist, like so:

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnBean({CounterService.class, GaugeService.class})
public class SomeMetrics {

    // Content ommitted for brevity.
}
```

I don't know which solution is the more correct one for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, @ThomasKåsene. I'll try creating all the beans as suggested by @AndyWilkinson and will definitely play with `@ConditionalOnBean`.

Comment: But actually I thought that `@ConditionalOnBean` is used to determine if the bean should be created, not for ordering. As injection is executed after instantiating all the beans, this should not be the issue.

Comment: It _is_ used for determining whether or not beans should be created. What I mean is that your context doesn't even contain any of the beans that `SomeMetrics` requires, because your test doesn't set them up. While I agree that you ought to create all the beans manually for auto-configuration, I don't think that's the source of the problem in this case.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, now I got your point. Actually I've expected Spring Boot to handle creation of its beans. Seems that Actuator got missing somehow - anyway I thought about making it optional, so I'll try this, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Why not take some inspiration from some of Spring Boot's own tests for auto-configuration classes? For example, [JacksonAutoConfigurationTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfigurationTests.java).

When you're testing an auto-configuration class you typically want to test with different beans and configuration properties in the context so that you can verify that any `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` or `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotations work as expected. For this reason, the tests don't use `@SpringBootTest` or Spring Framework's test framework which require the same application context to be used for every test in the class.

I'd also avoid using `@ComponentScan` in an auto-configuration class. None of Spring Boot's auto-configuration uses it. Instead, your auto-configuration should define all of the components via `@Bean` methods or by importing other Java and XML-based configuration using `@Import` and `@ImportResource` respectively.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried the simplest way and it worked :) Guilty. But I'll get rid of `@ComponentScan` - most probably that will solve the problem.

Comment: Proposed a minor improvement to Spring Boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6794

Comment: This comment pointed me in the right direction and learned a bunch of stuff along the way.